# How to get raster resolution using GDAL

Tags: python, gdal

I'm using `gdal` lib for Python in a Jupyter Notebook environment.

I'd like to retrieve the resolution of a raster to use it in a gdal.warp call.

At the moment I do the following :

```
src = gdal.Open(mask)
ulx, xres, xskew, uly, yskew, yres  = src.GetGeoTransform()
```

but I get too much information. Is there a way to only retreive `xres` and `yres`?

Comment: because I really don't like to instantiate useless variables. I try to clarify and organize a working code ;-)

Comment: Not adding as an answer as it's *ugly*, but you could use slice notation: `xres, yres  = src.GetGeoTransform()[1:6:4]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google says no. But a "workaround" could be to use [operator.itemgetter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272160/access-multiple-elements-of-list-knowing-their-index):

```
import gdal, operator
src = gdal.Open(mask)
xres, yres = operator.itemgetter(1,5)(src.GetGeoTransform())
```

Answer (score 9):

If you only want to avoid the unused variables use this code:

```
import gdal
...
src = gdal.Open(mask)
_, xres, _, _, _, yres  = src.GetGeoTransform()
```

Comment: any drawbacks of that solution? possibilities that it won't work? this should be an answer.

Comment: I does work using Python 3.8.10 and gdal 3.1.4.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html#osgeo.gdal.Dataset.RasterXSize) worked for me in gdal version 3.4.1:

```py
src = gdal.Open(mask)
xres = src.RasterXSize
yres = src.RasterYSize
```