# Using spatial resolution in RCM

Tags: gdal, rasterio

I have some RCM data acquired at 3 meter resolution mode. This means that the range resolution is 3 meter and azimuth resolution is 1 meter.

The resolution can be confirmed by the following link. https://www.asc-csa.gc.ca/eng/satellites/radarsat/technical-features/characteristics.asp

Furthermore when I used gdal  to  get the raster resolution it comes out to be 1x1 as per the following suggestion
[How to get raster resolution using GDAL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/368003/how-to-get-raster-resolution-using-gdal/368008#368008)

The same resolution of 1x1 was obtained with rasterio,using raster.transform.(the suggestion to compute cell size in rasterio was obtained from the below link
[how to take cell size from raster using python or GDAL or RASTERIO](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/243639/how-to-take-cell-size-from-raster-using-python-or-gdal-or-rasterio))

As such ,I am not sure why the resolution from rasterio and gdal is coming out to be 1x1 when it should be actually 3x1.

Comment: I asked  my mentor ,and he says that the SLC's original resolution is indeed 3x1 so I am not sure why gdal is giving me 1x1.

Answer (score 0):

You need to process your SAR data from SLC to GRD (Ground range detected) in order to have square pixels.

Here is a post in the SNAP forum for example: https://forum.step.esa.int/t/slc-to-grd-workflow-different-steps/28733

You could also do this automatically using open source libaries in Python, such as [EOReader](https://eoreader.readthedocs.io/en/v0.21.0/notebooks/SAR.html).

> Discalimer: I am the maintainer of EOReader